# How do I make regions like eu,us and india which lead to the same papermc server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

As I said, I can't seem to find a solution to make multiple gateways (I'm not sure what its called) leading to the same server or the same world. A friend of mine made a a papermc server and made regions like eu.servername.ml and in.servername.ml. But he won't tell me how he did it. And he gave me a hint that he used node.js but I'm not sure if he really used that to make gateways or regions. But the ping on the us server is average 500 for me and I live near the region in so when I join it I have like 100 ping average. And I have to say he is good at coding stuff. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I'm new to stack exchange so I'm really sorry if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

*We* can't tell you what your friend did, if *he himself* won't tell you.

It nominally *sounds* like he's implemented something like [CloudFlare's regional caching](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-regional-services/)… but I've never heard of that in Minecraft.

For HTTP, there's plenty of opportunity for a regional proxy to improve performance, due to the static, cacheable content system. Even dynamic web content doesn't suffer terribly from asynchronous updating. (*e.g.*: If you have to wait 10 seconds for your regional proxy to update to see a new forum post, you'll barely even notice. But 10 seconds of lag in Minecraft would just be untenable.) There's a real difference between a *website*, and a real-time RPG with synchronous play and a physical, fast-paced combat system.

[Here's](https://hypixel.net/threads/proxy-eu-for-the-network.3620535/) a thread where even one of the biggest Minecraft servers, with a heavy international community, is apparently not even *considering* it (in fact, the idea is **so far** "out there" that the only responder gets the idea confused with non-proxying transfer packets.)

---

tl;dr: My best guess is that *either* your friend is lying for attention (e.g. the `in`, `eu`, etc. subdomains all just have the same underlying `A`/`AAAA` records), *or* he's implemented ("in Node") some kind of regional proxy which will only slightly *increase* latency for any international players. Regional proxies *have* a use-case, and Minecraft **isn't** it, unless he's done some *heavy* server-side modding as well.